# Intercepting java machine shutdown call?

Tags: java, application-shutdown

Is there any way to get notified of JVM shutting down or System.exit call before the actual shutdown? I want this, so my application will be able to make a clean exit.
I realize that such thing is unlikely to exist, but still, maybe there is something like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at [Runtime.addShutdownHook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread))

From the API docs:

The Java virtual machine shuts down in response to two kinds of events:

- The program exits normally, when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the exit (equivalently, System.exit) method is invoked, or
- The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing ^C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown.

Using `Runtime.addShutdownHook` you can run code in those cases.

Answer (score 3):

There's `Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` method that you might want to explore.