# Need my program to know where I left off

Tags: java, loops, memory, continue

So I'm trying to make clip card application. In other words, I'm making an application that counts how many coffees a customer purchases, and for every 10:th purchase the customer gets awarded a free one. I'm pretty much done with the loop, but I'm having difficulties with figuring out how to make my program remember where I left off. For example, lets say I have bought my 7th coffee and am leaving so I want to close the application; is there a way for the program to remember where to continue next time it is being run?

Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FelixNeww {

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Scanner key;
    String entry;
    int count = 0;
    String password = "knusan01";
    while(true) {
        System.out.println("Enter password: ");
        key = new Scanner(System.in);
        entry = key.nextLine();
        if(entry.compareTo(password) == 0){
            count++;
            System.out.println("You're one step closer to a free coffe! You have so far bought " 
            + count + " coffe(s)");
        }
        if(count == 10  && count != 0){
            System.out.println("YOU'VE GOT A FREE COFFE!");
            count = 0;
        }
        if(entry.compareTo(password) != 0){
            System.out.println("Wrong password! Try again.\n");
        }
    }
}

}
```

Thanks

Comment: Persistence is the word. You can use database to store the information.

Comment: write to a file and store it on your hard disk.. I don't think we need a DB for this..

Comment: other comments, you don't have to compare both count == 10  && count != 0, just count == 10. Also you can use entry.equals(password). And you can put the you got a "free coffe if statement" inside the first if

Comment: Generally speaking, persisting data to files has the advantage of simplicity (just read and write a new file), databases are better for efficiency, security, and large datasets, although they require a greater deal of understanding and have a language of their own. I would recommend going the file option to begin with, for the experience if nothing else.

Comment: So I'm very new with this stuff. How do I do this exactly, meaning how do I write to a file and make my program read it every time it is being run again??

Comment: Here's a handy guide: http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/java/code/408638/read-edit-and-write-to-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure the progress is saved, try looking into the RuntimeHook as said here: [Intercepting java machine shutdown call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564276/intercepting-java-machine-shutdown-call)

And what you need to do is store the data in a file, the current count. This can be done fairly easily with the following code:

```
public void saveToFile(int count)
{
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try
    {
        bw = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(new File("countStorage"))));
        bw.write(count);
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(bw != null)
        {
            try
            {
                bw.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}

public int readFromFile()
{
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try
    {
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File("countStorage"))));
        String line = br.readLine();
        int count = Integer.parseInt(line);
        return count;
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
        if(br != null)
        {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch(IOException e) {}
        }
    }
}
```